# Which jQuery version to reference for CDN?

Tags: jquery, cdn

I want to use Google's jQuery CDN so that the user has the best chance to already have a cached version of jQuery.

Now my question is, how do I determine what is the best version of jQuery to maximize the probability that the user already has a cached version?

Should I reference the latest version of jQuery? Or the most popular version?

For example, the latest version is currently jQuery 1.9.0, which was just released yesterday. But most sites probably are not referencing it yet, so I would be better off using 1.8.3?

I'm thinking that I could just look at the source code for Google or other popular websites and see which jQuery they're referencing, but I can't seem to find any reference to jQuery when I view the source.

Comment: Sounds like micro-optimization to me. The user will have to load all versions at some point anyway, looking at how many sites using different versions utilize the CDN libraries. I don't think this is worth even thinking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the most recent release after giving it a thorough test on your site.

Any performance gain you would get today by using an older release will be lost in a short time as other sites move up to the new release.

Looking at other sites isn't very helpful, I just tried a few. The releases are all over the place, Google, Twitter and Facebook don't appear to use jQuery (at least not by name) and stackoverflow is using 1.7.1

Answer (score 3):

Here's a market share chart: http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-jquery/1/all
Looks like 1.7 takes the cake...for now. 
You can see the 1.7.x stats by clicking the version: http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-jquery/1.7/all

Comment: at 1st 1.7 seems most used, but if you break it down, it's 19.8% * 52.2% for 1.7.2 vs 18.5% * 93.9% for 1.10.2

Comment: Great resource! Currently, the most used version is 1.11.3 (June, 2016).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently other sites do NOT move up to new releases very fast.
Below is the overall link from w3techs for ALL jquery versions that shows this. (It's been months since 2.0). And this matters for caching.  You'd want the most popular sites that your visitors visit most probably to host the same version. Althoug it is not permanent and you might want to consider things more in respect to other things.
The link is also a good reference for the future for this question. You can click deeper each time.
   **http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-jquery/all/all**